# Left Join + Where clause on Date Field

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

On the Right side of a Left Join, I am unable to set a Where clause on a Date field. It works perfectly if changed to an Inner Join, or if I set a Where on a non-date field.

This fails with a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error:

```
SELECT tblFuture.ContractNo
FROM tblFuture LEFT JOIN qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized
ON tblFuture.ContractNo = qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.ContractNo
WHERE qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.Dt=#2/1/2014#;
```

This works perfectly:

```
SELECT tblFuture.ContractNo
FROM tblFuture INNER JOIN qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized
ON tblFuture.ContractNo = qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.ContractNo
WHERE qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.Dt=#2/1/2014#;
```

As does:

```
SELECT tblFuture.ContractNo
FROM tblFuture LEFT JOIN qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized
ON tblFuture.ContractNo = qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.ContractNo
WHERE qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.ContractNo=41012;
```

Field ContractNo is Long type, field Dt is from a query which calls DateSerial(someyear, somemonth, someday). This smells like an Access bug, but Googling turns up nothing for me. I'm using Access 2010 32-bit.

Comment: move the criteria to the join.

Comment: Is qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.Dt a date field?

Comment: Sun W Kim: yes. It is generated from a function which is returning a Date datatype (DateSerial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using outer joins you either have to use OR null in where clause or more appropriately, filter before the Cartesian form the join is generated by filtering on the join itself.  This only applies to filters on tables which are not returning all their results (qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized in this case).  The Cartesian results in null records from the qryActualDeliveriesDump_Summarized  The where clause filters out those null records, but you want them. So what to do?

Solution: Add the filter to the join so it takes place before the Cartesian is generated, or add `or field is null` to where clause.

```
SELECT tblFuture.ContractNo
FROM tblFuture LEFT JOIN qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized
ON tblFuture.ContractNo = qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.ContractNo
and qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.Dt=#2/1/2014#;
```

OR (though this isn't as clean)

```
SELECT tblFuture.ContractNo
FROM tblFuture LEFT JOIN qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized
ON tblFuture.ContractNo = qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.ContractNo
WHERE (qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.Dt=#2/1/2014# OR qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.Dt is null);
```

The latter has it's own issues such as if the field can be null, you have no way to separate out records nulled due to the join vs null values in the base table.  It more often than not is a non-issue, but it can be problematic in certain conditions, which is why adding criteria to the join is a better answer.

However in access...
it has to be broken into Two steps: 1st get a set of data containing the filtered results, next do the join.  Otherwise again, the null values from the outer join are eliminated.

```
SELECT tblFuture.ContractNo
    FROM tblFuture 
    LEFT JOIN (Select * from qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized where   qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized.Dt=#2/1/2014#) B on 
    ON tblFuture.ContractNo = B.ContractNo
```

Comment: The first one returns "Join expression not supported", the second one gives the same "Data mismatch error."

Comment: xQbert: Great find!

SELECT tblFuture.ContractNo
FROM tblFuture LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM qryActualDeliveriesDump_summarized WHERE YEAR(Dt)=2014) AS innie
ON tblFuture.ContractNo = innie.ContractNo;

Comment: I'm sure in a real database your other suggestions would have worked perfectly, but Access didn't like em. Still accepting answer because of KB link.